# Power BI :: CALENDARAUTO() stop creating dates for current month

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have two calendars: `Calendar 1` and `Calendar 2` that I have been using for the last months without problems.

Today (21/09/2023) I open my Power BI Desktop and I realize that all dates for September are greyed out:

[image]

I can select dates till the 31 of August but the whole month of September is just not there.

This is interesting because the calendar itself is created this way:

```
Calendar 2 = CALENDARAUTO()
```

And it's not connected to any other table:

[image]

I perfectly remember that I could select the **18th of September** just yesterday.

And today nothing.
Both on the Power BI Desktop and Power BI online.

What might possibly have changed?

Answer (score 1):

User error!

A change in the Azure Cost Management export made a Logic App to fail. The month-to-date CSV file wasn't shipped to the Storage Account.

September wasn't showing because the data weren't there.